# He uses my car for one hour every day. vs He has been using my car for one hour every day

Tags: grammar, speech, present-progressive, perfect-continuous

What is the **difference** between **Present Simple** and **Present Perfect Continuous** when we **use** them for "**something that happens again and again in the present**".

Ex:

He uses my car for one hour every day.

He has been using my car for one hour every day.

---

I work here.

I have been working here.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

> He uses my car for one hour every day.

This indicates the normal state of affairs. There is no indication that the situation is likely to end. It may have been going on for years.

> He has been using my car for one hour every day.

This indicates a temporary state of affairs. We assume that there will be a definite finish. We also get the sense that this may not have started very long ago.

Edit

Looking at other answers, I see there may be some disagreement. There is a great difference between what is theoretically possible when using tenses and what real people actually say in given contexts.

Although in theory the two sentences *could* be used to mean the same thing, the idea that they always do, is not correct - otherwise there would be no need for the present perfect at all and we could dispense with it. There is however a possibility that the nuance is different in different countries. In England where I am from, there is a clear distinction in usage.

Comment: Your distinction exists and has the same nuance in the United States.

Answer (score 1):

The first is the enduring present tense.  The implication is that he's been using your car for a while, and that he will continue to do so.

The second is the present perfect progressive tense, which indicates an unspecified interval of past time for an action ongoing during that interval, an action that continues up to right now.  There's no implication for the future:  you may add "but I'm going to stop loaning him my car" or "and that's OK with me."

"I works here" is ungrammatical.  The first person requires "I work here."  The second two sentences follow the pattern of the first two.

Comment: I corrected the grammatical mistake. So this means both the formations are interchangeable?

Comment: @user134145 They're parallel.